# I want to find all the IP's to which outgoing traffic is going from the nodes/pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

in Kubernetes I want to find all the IP's to which outgoing traffic is going from the nodes/pods. Does anyone know how to find out? because once we establish those IP's we need to give it to users so that they need to whitelist from their side.

how can i perform simple test on each node / pod to see the outgoing IP address that will do the requests?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on GKE and your cluster is public

Your Outing going IP will be always **Node's IP** on which your POD is running.

This will list all the external **IPs** to Node, and check all the External ones that will be outgoing IPs based on PODs running on which node.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

If you want to quickly verify outgoing IP

Go inside any POD using the **exec**

```
kubectl exec -it <POD name> -n <namespace name> -- /bin/sh
```

and run the command

```
curl https://ifconfig.me/
```

it will response your out going IP which will be in your case Node's IP on which POD is running.

Comment: Hi Harsh, Thank you so much for the details. Actually ours is a private GKE cluster and i think the mentioned commands works for them as well right? or do i need to execute different commands? because for most of the PODS/NODES I'm able to get egress IP using `curl https://ifconfig.me/`. For few pods i'm getting curl is not found. can i know how can i find egress if there is no curl in a POD?

Comment: you can install the curl in that pod if that is possible, else you can try an alternative of curl or python or node small script which can do http request simply as that.

Answer (score 0):

Needed the same info for whitelisting/unblocking purposes, this helped

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide | awk '{print $7}'
```

Alternatively

```
kubectl get nodes \
--selector=kubernetes.io/role!=master \
-o jsonpath={.items[*].status.addresses[?\(@.type==\"ExternalIP\"\)].address}
```